# I am using full Push down optimization. getting error cannot cast type time without timezone to timestamp without timezone

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am using full push down optimization for one mapping which is having delete insert logic with help of update stategy. In the target table, there is one column with datatype Time without time zone. In the session logs, I can see it is trying to delete the view created as part of PDO. It is using cast function to convert time column into a timestamp instead of a time column. It is giving error:

```
cannot cast type time without timezone to timestamp without time zone
```

Comment: time and timestamp are different data types. i do not think infa can handle `time` data type in some DB like mysql. Try creating a new string column with time part in `hh:mi:ss` format and link it to the time column in tgt.

Comment: Thanks Kaushik!
In source table, time column is having data type VARCHAR(6). In source qualifier we are converting it to time format HH24MISS. in push down optimization it is trying to delete from temporary view created for target table there it casting time column as timestamp column there it is failing.For other date columns in target table it is working.so is it limitation of PDO or there is work around for this issue.We are working with postgres sql DB.